# How do Windows 7 optimize memory usage automatically?

Tags: windows-7

When installing Windows 7 on a system with memory of 4GB or lower, it will use about 500mb RAM on a clean system, but if installing on a system with 8GB or higher memory, it will use about 1GB on a same clean environment, so what settings does windows automatically changed?

Comment: Questions are not the place to put a rant, if you have a problem take it to meta.superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

The main thing Windows will use with spare unused memory is make a larger filesystem cache so frequently read files will have a copy kept in memory to provide faster read access.

Comment: Besides of cache, windows also will preload most frequently used programs to RAM to speed up start of that programs (Service: superfetch)